# How extract jsonb column in fields by key

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm using postgresql and postgis plugin.

I have stored data with this scheme: `table_id is primary key, properties is a jsonb and geom as geometry(GeometryZ,4326)`;

If I make this request: `select table_id, properties, geom from nametable` return all info with table_id as integer, properties as jsonb and geom as geometry(GeometryZ,4326).

I would like a query where properties return table_id, a list of column where name of column is the key of value and his value and geom. For example, if properties has name and density return a response like this: `table_id | name | density | geom |`, but I dont know the name of properties so I think that should be a query inside that query that get name of keys.

The closest I've been to get it, its with this query: `select jsonb_object_keys(properties) as key from nametable;`

Thanks

EDIT:

First, I have stored a field as jsonb in my postgressql database, so I would like extract that jsonb to columns. But have stored differents tables that contains differents properties into jsonb column.

So, the idea is get a query where select table_id, properties(extracted in multiple columns) and geom.

1 - With this I have the name of keys: `select jsonb_object_keys(properties) as key from nametable group by key;`

2 - With keys get in column all values of each key.

3 - Return a query where when I call it, return me table_id, column of properties extracted from jsonb, geom from nametable;

My problem is that I dont know how generate that query with sub-queries.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide 1 some sample data 2) exactly what you expect as output and 3) tell us what went wrong with your query.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit the question to explain me better

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html)?

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 
    table_id, 
    properties->>'name' AS name,
    properties->>'density' AS density,
    geom 
  FROM t)
SELECT * FROM j WHERE j.name = 'Alabama';
```

Comment: Thats good but I dont know the keys of jsonb column.. in this case is name and density but in other will be different keys.. so I would like to get dinamically the keys and make the query as you post

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all people that help me.

Here is the code with queries to work with a tile server.

I used this query to get an array of keys:

> const sql = `SELECT ARRAY_AGG(f) as keys FROM (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(properties) f FROM ${options.layerName} group by f) u`;

And later, a function to create a query to get each property as a column called `generateSQL`,

```
/** CONSTANTS **/
const TILE_SIZE = 256;
const PROJECTION_STRING = '+init=epsg:3857';

/** LIBRARIES **/
var zlib = require('zlib');
var express = require('express');
var mapnik = require('mapnik');
var Promise = require('promise');
var SphericalMercator = require('sphericalmercator');

const { pool } = require('../postgressql/config');

var mercator = new SphericalMercator({
    size: TILE_SIZE
});

mapnik.register_default_input_plugins();

var app = express();

app.get('/:namelayer/:z/:x/:y.pbf', (req, res, next) => {
    var options = {
        x: parseInt(req.params.x),
        y: parseInt(req.params.y),
        z: parseInt(req.params.z),
        layerName: req.params.namelayer
    };

   const sql = `SELECT ARRAY_AGG(f) as keys FROM (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(properties) f FROM ${options.layerName} group by f) u`;
    try {
        pool.query(sql, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    ok: false,
                    message: error
                });
            }

            const keys = (results && results.rows && results.rows.length > 0 && results.rows[0].keys && results.rows[0].keys.length >0) ? results.rows[0].keys.slice() : [];
            const sql = generateSQL(options, keys);

            makeVectorTile(options, sql).then( (vectorTile) => {
                zlib.deflate(vectorTile, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
                    }

                    res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'deflate');
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-protobuf');
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    return res.send(data);
                });
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).send({
            error: e.toString(),
        });
    }
});

function generateSQL(options, keys) {

    if (keys.length === 0) {
        return `select table_id, geom from ${options.layerName}`;
    } else {
        let sql = "";
        keys.forEach( key => {
            sql = sql + `(properties->>'${key}') as ${key},`;
        });
        sql = `select table_id, ${sql} geom from ${options.layerName}`
        return sql;
    }
};

function makeVectorTile(options, sql) {

    var extent = mercator.bbox(options.x, options.y, options.z, false, '3857');
    var map = new mapnik.Map(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, PROJECTION_STRING);
    map.extent = extent;

    var layer = new mapnik.Layer(options.layerName);
    layer.datasource = new mapnik.Datasource({
        type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
        dbname: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        // table: options.layerName,
        table: `(${sql}) as tile`,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    });

    layer.styles = ['default'];
    map.add_layer(layer);

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var vtile = new mapnik.VectorTile(parseInt(options.z), parseInt(options.x), parseInt(options.y));
        map.render(vtile, function (err, vtile) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log(`${vtile.getData().length} KB`);
            resolve(vtile.getData());
        });
    });
};

module.exports = app;
```